# Can you only use webHttpBinding with REST?

Tags: wcf, rest

I know you can use multiple bindings, but if you implement a REST Service, must you use the webHttpBinding?

Comment: That's what WebHttpBinding *means*...   What other binding would you rather use?

Comment: I don't, I was just curious if you could build a REST-based service with wsHttpBinding as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The webHttpBinding is what tells the WCF framework to communicate in a RESTful fashion - any other binding would define a different protocol.  In your comment, you ask about wsHttpBinding - If you used that binding, you would not have a REST service, you'd have a SOAP web service.

Comment: ok, that clears it up. I'm new to WCF and REST and running into many issues.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use directly WebHttpBinding. You can also use custom binding or your own binding but these bindings have to use HttpTransportBindingElement  and WebMessageEncodingBindingElement. Both these binding elements are used by WebHttpBinding.